# JSON get user id's in nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I get all the user ids in the nested array JSON, I'm using the following code to get the JSON response:

```
var userListObj = JSON.stringify(result.items);
console.log(userListObj);
```

any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

```js
{  
   "current_page":1,
   "per_page":100,
   "total_entries":3,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12729498,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test1",
            "email":"test1",
            "login":"test1",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-16T14:56:24Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T18:23:35Z",
            "last_request_at":"2016-05-17T19:23:37Z",
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      },
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12768158,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test2",
            "email":"",
            "login":"test2",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-17T18:25:13Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T18:25:13Z",
            "last_request_at":null,
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      },
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12769692,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test3",
            "email":null,
            "login":"test3",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-17T19:22:55Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T19:22:55Z",
            "last_request_at":null,
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: 1) Learn how to [access properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) 2) Learn how to [use a `for` loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) 3) Don't convert an object to JSON when you're trying to pull data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var json = {  
   "current_page":1,
   "per_page":100,
   "total_entries":3,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12729498,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test1",
            "email":"test1",
            "login":"test1",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-16T14:56:24Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T18:23:35Z",
            "last_request_at":"2016-05-17T19:23:37Z",
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      },
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12768158,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test2",
            "email":"",
            "login":"test2",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-17T18:25:13Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T18:25:13Z",
            "last_request_at":null,
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      },
      {  
         "user":{  
            "id":12769692,
            "owner_id":51603,
            "full_name":"test3",
            "email":null,
            "login":"test3",
            "phone":null,
            "website":null,
            "created_at":"2016-05-17T19:22:55Z",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17T19:22:55Z",
            "last_request_at":null,
            "external_user_id":null,
            "facebook_id":null,
            "twitter_id":null,
            "blob_id":null,
            "custom_data":null,
            "twitter_digits_id":null,
            "user_tags":null
         }
      }
   ]
};

var arr = [];
json.items.forEach(function(item) {
    arr.push(item.user.id);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/59tahwc6/1/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer i will also look into what Mike C recommended

Answer (score 1):

If you apply what @Mike C has commented you get something like this:

```
var formattedJson = JSON.parse(json);

    for (i=0;i<formattedJson.items.length;i++){
        console.log(formattedJson.items[i].user.id);
    }
```

The formattedJson depends whether you get a JSON as string or as valid JSON, if so you don't need to use `JSON.parse`, you can just access it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, commented and with error checking:

```
var x = '{"current_page":1, "per_page":100, "total_entries":3, "items":[{"user":{"id":12729498}},{"user":{"id":12768158}},{"user":{"id":12769692}}]}';

// Parse the JSON
var userListObj = JSON.parse(x);

// Check if any entries exist
if (typeof userListObj.items != 'undefined' && userListObj.items.length > 0)
{
    // Loop through each user
    for (var i in userListObj.items)
    {
        // Check if a user ID exists
        if (typeof userListObj.items[i].user.id != 'undefined')
        {
            // Output the user ID to the console
            console.log (userListObj.items[i].user.id);
        }
    }
}
```